# What is a manifest authoring warning?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, manifest, compiler-warnings

Anyone knows what this mean? Care to shed some light?
Got this warning while compiling a MFC project in VS2005.

```
..\..\..\Shared\res\zenOn_common.manifest : manifest authoring warning 81010002: Unrecognized Element "requestedPrivileges" in namespace "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this thread.:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/d9c47905-3d84-4275-b277-9ffe06001f80

It solutes the problem in some cases.

Edit:
It seems that there is/was a problem with manifest files including an date that was older than the build date. Strange...

Comment: hi bastianneu, thanks for the link to the thread... seems the correct solution to the warning... will try it out...